# Find parameters for process to become gaussian

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-analysis, characteristic-functions

Find parameters $ a,b,c $ for process $ aW_t^2+cW_{bt^2+a} $ to make it gaussian.

---

The process is gaussian if

$$ E \left [ \exp \left ( i \sum_{l=1}^{k} s_l Y_{t_l} \right ) \right ] =
\exp \left ( -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j,l} \sigma_{j,l}s_j s_l + i \sum_{l=1}^{k} \mu_l s_l \right )  $$

$ \mu = E[aW_t^2+cW_{bt^2+a}] = at $

$ \sigma = \operatorname{Var}[aW_t^2+cW_{bt^2+a}] = 2ac\,\operatorname{cov}(W_t^2, cW_{bt^2+a}) + 3a^2t^2 + c^2(bt^2+a)$, if calculated correctly

What should I do with $2ac\,\operatorname{cov}(W_t^2, cW_{bt^2+a})$?

And how to get rid of mean.

Comment: To be clear, do you want this to be a Gaussian process, or just to find parameters such that $a W_t^2 + cW_{bt^2+a}$ is Gaussian for some fixed $t$?

Comment: I want to find parameters

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if you want to find parameters such that $aW_t^2 + c W_{bt^2+a}$ is a Gaussian process, or just that $aW_t^2 + cW_{bt^2+a}$ is Gaussian for some fixed $t$?

Comment: The most obvious choice for $aW_t^2+cW_{bt^2+a}$ to be a Gaussian process is $a=0\,.$

Comment: Yes, but the objective is to find all parameters that make process gaussian, except $t$

Answer (score 1):

We are first looking for conditions on $(a,b,c)$ that guarantee that  fixed $t$, $aW_t^2+cW_{bt^2+a}$ has a Gaussian distribution. Such a random variable has the same distribution as $aX^2+Y$, where $(X,Y)$ is a Gaussian vector.
Substracting and adding $KX$ for a constant $K$ such that $Y-KX$ is independent of $X$, we are in the situation where $aU^2+KU+V$ has a Gaussian distribution, where $(U,V)$ is a vector of independent normal random variables.

If $Z'$, $Z+Z'$ have a  Gaussian distribution and $Z$ is independent of $Z'$, then $Z$ has a Gaussian distribution (look at the characteristic functions of the involved random variable).

If $a\neq 0$, then $aU^2+KU$ cannot have a Gaussian distribution because of properties of the range of a second order polynomial.

Therefore, we need $a=0$. Now I think that checking that $cW_{bt^2}$ is Gaussian should not be a hard task.